# How to convert list of QImage elements into video file?

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I need to know how to convert list of `QImage` into video file - to be specific an `avi` file - without using OpenCV ?

Comment: You can't do that with qt.

Comment: @dtech then how to do it?

Comment: Why do not you want to use openCV?

Comment: You will have to use a 3rd party library, ffmpeg, libav, libvnc, gstreamer... either will do.

Comment: @eyllanesc should I need to compile openCV source code or just use the dll files ?

Comment: To use a C ++ library for compilation time only compiled libraries (.dlls in windows) and headers (.h) are required, and for use only compiled libraries (.dlls in windows)

Comment: @eyllanesc so where to get the dll files of openCV?

Comment: When compiling opencv, it generates the .dlls